# MySQL - Create table with virtual columns based on conditions

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a table that contains indexed virtual columns that are referencing a JSON.

I've created the table which contains a virtual column named "amount". The problem is that the JSON doesn't always contain the key "amount". Sometimes it's named "presentationAmount".

Is it possible to put a condition in place for this?

When the JSON contains the key "threeDSecure" that's when "presentationAmount" is used, otherwise "amount" is used.

Here's my create table code:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
    id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    json JSON DEFAULT NULL,
    type VARCHAR(12) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json->>"$.transaction.type"),
    uuid VARCHAR(32) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json->>"$.transaction.payload.id"),
    holder VARCHAR(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json->>"$.transaction.payload.card.holder"),
    amount DECIMAL(11,2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json->>"$.transaction.payload.amount"),
    resultCode VARCHAR(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json->>"$.transaction.payload.result.code"),
    processingTime DATETIME GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json->>"$.transaction.payload.timestamp"),
    paymentType VARCHAR(2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json->>"$.transaction.payload.paymentType"),
    paymentBrand VARCHAR(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json->>"$.transaction.payload.paymentBrand"),
    eci INT(2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json->>"$.transaction.payload.eci"),
    recurringType VARCHAR(9) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json->>"$.transaction.payload.recurringType"),
    clearingInstitute VARCHAR(30) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json->>"$.transaction.payload.resultDetails.clearingInstituteName"),
    merchantTransactionId VARCHAR(64) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json->>"$.transaction.payload.merchantTransactionId"),
    divisionName VARCHAR(32) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json->>"$.division.name"),
    divisionUuid VARCHAR(32) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json->>"$.division.uuid"),
    merchantName VARCHAR(32) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json->>"$.merchant.name"),
    merchantUuid VARCHAR(32) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json->>"$.merchant.uuid"),
    channelName VARCHAR(32) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json->>"$.channel.name"),
    channelUuid VARCHAR(32) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json->>"$.channel.uuid"),
    INDEX typeIndex (type),
    INDEX idIndex (uuid),
    INDEX holderIndex (holder),
    INDEX amountIndex (amount),
    INDEX resultCodeIndex (resultCode),
    INDEX timestampIndex (processingTime),
    INDEX paymentTypeIndex (paymentType),
    INDEX paymentBrandIndex (paymentBrand),
    INDEX recurringTypeIndex (recurringType),
    INDEX clearingInstituteIndex (clearingInstitute),
    INDEX merchantTransactionIdIndex (merchantTransactionId),
    INDEX divisonNameIndex (divisionName),
    INDEX divisionUuidIndex (divisionUuid),
    INDEX merchantNameIndex (merchantName),
    INDEX merchantUuidindex (merchantUuid),
    INDEX channelNameIndex (channelName),
    INDEX channelUuidIndex (channelUuid)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `IF()` expression.

```
amount DECIMAL(11,2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
    (IF(JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(json, 'one', '$.transaction.payload.threeDSecure'), 
        json->>"$.transaction.payload.presentationAmount", 
        json->>"$.transaction.payload.amount")),
```

See the documentation of [`JSON_CONTAINS_PATH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains-path) for details of its use.

Comment: What does the 'one' do in that statement mate?

Comment: It doesn't do anything, but it's a required argument. If you give `JSON_CONTAINS_PATH()` multiple paths, you have to specify whether it should look for all of them or any one of them. It's in the documentation.